Working with ALVAR library on Noetic
I am working on precision landing and came to know that ALVAR library is not available for ROS noetic. What is the way around? and are there any alternative libraries that can be used?

I successfully built Alvar for ROS Noetic from source, see if this works for you.
Prerequisites

Must have Catkin workspace folder setup and Catkin build working
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make


~/.bashrc must have a command to setup Catkin environment
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash


~/.bashrc must have a command to setup ROS environment
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash



Step 1: Clone Alvar using noetic-devel branch
cd ~/catkin_ws/src    
git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/ar_track_alvar.git -b noetic-devel

Step 2: Install dependencies
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
rosdep install -y --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro noetic

Step 3: Build
cd ~/catkin_ws/
catkin_make
source ~/.bashrc

Step 4: Test
Try one of the following depending on your use case:

Use one of the launch files as described in https://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar
Add a block to your own launch file which uses one of the nodes in ar_alvar_track package and provides parameters (presumably just copy and paste from one of the launch files in ar_track_alvar, which you can access now since you have the source cloned)
Run one of the nodes in ar_alvar_track package directly:
rosrun ar_track_alvar individualMarkers \
  _marker_size:=9.577 \
  _output_frame:="camera_link" \
  _cam_image_topic:="/camera/depth_registered/points" \
  _cam_info_topic:="/camera/rgb/camera_info" \
  _max_new_marker_error:=0.5 \
  _max_track_error:=0.5



